# Provide a dynamic value for Angular Constant in Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a constant which is injected into a controller and I need to write a test which changes this constant and expects different results. I can use `$provide` to mock the constant but according to articles I've found online, I need to do it in the module declaration, which I believe is like this:

```
beforeEach(module("someModule"));

beforeEach(function () {
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.constant('someConstant', false);
    });
});
```

I later load the controller like this:

```
function createController() {

    view = $controller(
        "someController",
        {
            $scope: $injector.get("$rootScope").$new()
        });

}
```

Where `$controller`, `$scope` and `$injector` are all injected in my main `beforeEach`

This does provide the constant and it does change if I change the value in my `beforeEach`. But only for the entire test suite. I want to change this constant in a `describe` or an `it` but I'm not sure how. If I move the `$provide` down to a `describe` or `it`, I get the error:

> Error: Injector already created, can not register a module!

I could just create a new file and that is probably what I'm going to do but is there a way I can $provide a dynamic value?

Comment: Try nesting the `beforeEach()` that gives the value to your constant *inside* the `describe()`. You will have to repeat some setup code for each `describe()`, but I believe it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider such a code

#### controller

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
.controller('someController', function($scope, someConstant) {
    $scope.someProvidedValue = someConstant;
})
```

and test for it

#### controller spec

```
describe('module', function () {

    beforeEach(module("someModule"));

    var createController;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$injector_) {
        scope = _$injector_.get("$rootScope").$new()
        createController = function createController(scope, obj) {
            _$controller_("someController", {
                $scope: scope,
                someConstant: obj.someConstant
            });
        }
    }))

    it('someConstant', function () {
        expect(scope.someProvidedValue).toBe(undefined)
        createController(scope, {
            someConstant: false
        })
        expect(scope.someProvidedValue).toBe(false)
    })

    it('someConstant', function () {
        expect(scope.someProvidedValue).toBe(undefined)
        createController(scope, {
            someConstant: true
        })
        expect(scope.someProvidedValue).toBe(true)
    })
})
```

In the mean time I'm looking for looks nicer solution.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I thought I tried some variation of this but obviously I must have been slightly wrong! Cheers